# Generate documentation from annotated Acceleo

Tags: documentation-generation, acceleo

As I'm currently doing research on model-based testing I often have write a lot of acceleo code. I'm currently at a point where I asked myself whether it is possible to generate automatically a documentation from my annotated acceleo templates and queries.

So my first step was to try out Doxygen to generate the documentation. I simply used the default settings of the doxygen generator except that I added the *.mtl ending to *FILE_PATTERN* and checked the *EXTRACT_ALL* option. But unfortunately, doxygen only parses the Java classes that run the acceleo code.

My question is, are there any options I miss to activate so that doxygen will work with acceleo? Or are there other alternatives?